# Can constructor call another class's constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class A {
public:
    A(int v) {
        _val = v;
    }

private:
    int _val;
};

class B {
public:
    B(int v) {
        a = A(v); // i think this is the key point
    }

private:
    A a;
};

int main() {
    B b(10);

    return 0;
}
```

compiler says:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(int)’:
test.cpp:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
test.cpp:5: note: candidates are: A::A(int)
test.cpp:3: note:                 A::A(const A&)
```

I've learned Java, and I don't know how to deal with this in C++.
Searching for a couple days, plz tell me can C++ do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a **[Member Initialization List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**

```
B(int v):a(v)
{
}
```

With:

```
B(int v) 
{
        a = A(v); // i think this is the key point
}
```

`a` is being ***assigned*** a value and not being **initialized**(*which is what you intend*), Once the body of an constructor begins `{`, all its members are already constructed.

**Why do you get an error?**
The compiler constructs `a` before constructor body `{` begins, the compiler uses the no argument constructor of `A` because you didn't tell it otherwise<sup>Note 1</sup>, Since the default no argument constructor is not available hence the error.

**Why is the default no argument constructor not generated implicitly?**
Once you provide ***any*** constructor for your class, the implicitly generated no argument constructor is not generated anymore. You provided overloads for constructor of `A` and hence there is no implicit generation of the no argument constructor.

<sup>Note 1</sup>
Using Member Initializer List is the way to tell the compiler to use particular overloaded version of the constructor and not the default no argument constructor.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use initialization lists:

```
class B {
public:
    B(int v) : a(v) { // here

    }

private:
    A a;
};
```

Otherwise the compiler will try to construct an `A` using the default constructor. Since you don't provide one, you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, but you haven't provided a default constructor for `A`(one that takes no parameters or all parameters have default values), so you can only initialize it in the **initializer list**:

```
B(int v) : a(v) 
{
}
```

This is because before the constructor body enters, `a` will be constructed (or attempted to be constructed) with the default constructor (which isn't available).